# Trying to retrieve boolean value from a function in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to get a variable from the function that represents the boolean status of the charge_port_door_open variable, something like this:
let ChargePortStatus = (DATA.response.charge_state.charge_port_door_open)
The function does print a correct boolean, however, 'DATA' cannot be found in scope outside the function.

Edit: Thank you all very much for the help!
This is my first question posted on this website and I wasnt expecting for help to arrive so quickly!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Root: Codable {
let response: TEST1
}

struct TEST1: Codable {
let charge_state: TEST2
}

struct TEST2: Codable {
let charge_port_door_open: Bool
}

public func RequestVehicleData() {
 
    let url = URL(string: "https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles/:id/vehicle_data")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    let DATA = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
    print(DATA.response.charge_state.charge_port_door_open)            
}
        task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like a mess. Please format/indent it correctly before posting it here.

Comment: Just do the things you need to do inside the closure. And please,  this is Swift. Capitalized and snake_case variable names are uncool.

Comment: Well I had to put their json names to decode them so there was no other way around snake_case.

Comment: Yes there is a way around that and it’s called CodingKeys, well worth researching. On another note, I see you have made an edit and thanked people but that is not really how it works around here. If people’s answers have helped you then upvote them and if one clearly solved your problem then mark it as accepted. If on the other hand you don’t fully understand the answer then provide some feedback by posting a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `dataTask` is asynchronous, you have to modify your method to return a value in a closure. A simple version without any error handling can look like this:

```
public func requestVehicleData(completion: @escaping ((Bool?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles/:id/vehicle_data")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let responseData = data, let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: responseData) {
            completion(response.response.charge_state.charge_port_door_open)        
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

You can also play around with the [Swift Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html) and user new `async/await` API for the same purpose.

P.S. When you have a chance, take a look at some [basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#) and [API Design Guideline](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

Comment: Hello! I have tried to use your solution but I don't know how to call the function. Every time I try to call it { EX: requestVehicleData(completion: ((Bool?) -> Void)) } I get this error : Cannot convert value of type '((Bool?) -> Void).Type' to expected argument type '(Bool?) -> Void'

Comment: you call it like this: `requestVehicleData { value in print(value) }`

Answer (score 0):

Two simple approaches (if you don't want the call-site to have to use a completion block - which is also a perfectly good solution described in Maksym's answer) are..

1. perform any actions you need to perform with the value inside of the closure
2. create an optional property with a `didSet` on whatever owns `RequestVehicleData`. That way you can set the value within the closure and trigger the desired actions. An example for this would be:

   ```
   class VehicleDataManager {
       private var root: Root? {
           didSet {
               doSomething(with: root)
           }
       }

       public func RequestVehicleData() {

           let url = URL(string: "https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles/:id/vehicle_data")!
           var request = URLRequest(url: url)
           request.httpMethod = "GET"
           request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
           request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
               root = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
               print(DATA.response.charge_state.charge_port_door_open)            
           }
           task.resume()
        }
   }
   ```

The value is fetched asynchronously, so it will only be safely accessible in places that are guaranteed to get run after it has been returned.

Side note: I know this might have just been for the sake of a "quick and dirty" test function, but I would highly recommend not getting in the habit of force-unwrapping values that very well could be nil